# How to sort dropdown list of objects in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, jhipster

I have:

```html
<select class="form-control" id="field_productDelivered" name="productDelivered" ng-model="vm.productDelivered.productDelivered" ng-options="product as product.name for product in vm.products track by product.id">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Output is sorted by id, but I need to have it sorted by name.
I tried:

```html
ng-options="product as product.name for product in vm.products track by product.id" | toArray | orderBy : 'name'"
```

but in console I get:
`TypeError: dbg is undefined`.
How can I sort it using Angular?

Comment: also track by statements always are after any filtering that may be done.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should get you output going in the right direction. Hope it helps! Included a working example, with it the third param true to show items in reverse order.

This is what I imagine yours will look like to get them ordered accordingly.

```
ng-options="product as product.name for product in vm.products | toArray | orderBy : 'name' track by product.id"
```

```js
function exampleController($scope) {
  $scope.phones = [{
    model: 'anteater'
  }, {
    model: 'bee'
  }, {
    model: 'cat'
  }];
}

angular
  .module('example', [])
  .controller('exampleController', exampleController);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" ng-app="example">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="exampleController">
    <div class="row">
      <ol>
        <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | orderBy: 'model': true track by $index" ng-bind="phone.model"></li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a `working example` as same as in your case.

It looks you had the following two things which should be sorted.

1. You have closed the `double quotes` before the `" | toArray` in
   `"product as product.name for product in vm.products track by
   product.id" | toArray | orderBy : 'name'"`
2. Also the `track by product.id` should be at the end after the
   filters like `ng-options="product as product.name for product in vm.products | toArray | orderBy : 'name' track by product.id"`

You can see the `working example` below as same as the one in the question.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('TestController', function() {
  this.productDelivered = {};
  this.products = {
    'product1': {
      id: 4,
      name: 'product B'
    },
    'product2': {
      id: 3,
      name: 'product D'
    },
    'product3': {
      id: 1,
      name: 'product A'
    },
    'product4': {
      id: 2,
      name: 'product C'
    }  
  };
});

app.filter("toArray", function() {
        return function(input) {
            if(!input) return;

            if (input instanceof Array) {
                return input;
            }

            return $.map(input, function(val) {
                return val;
            });
        };
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="TestController as vm">
<select class="form-control" id="field_productDelivered" name="productDelivered" ng-model="vm.productDelivered.productDelivered" 
        ng-options="product as product.name for product in vm.products | toArray | orderBy : 'name' track by product.id">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
</div>
```